# Writing to Console on async event

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webclient

I am using `WebClient` to submit an array of HTTP requests to a server (order doesn't matter).

Instead of sending a request, waiting, sending, waiting, etc. I wanted to send as many as possible and just wait for the responses as they come, however, and issue arises when I need to write to the console after a specific request was completed.

The output looks fine, then I start to get multiple request messages, then a group of Responses/Errors, rather than the Request Message followed by the response.

Is there any way to block any other Console Writes until each block finishes?

```
int currentRequest = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < requests.Count; i++) {
    using (var webclient = new WebClient())
    {
        webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Info("Request: " + currentRequest + "/" + requests.Count);
            if (e.Error == null) {
                // Do something with e.Result
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
            }
            currentRequest += 1;
        };
        webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("URL HERE"));
    }
}
```

**On another note:** I don't feel like this is how I should be handling requests (asynchronously), correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to block any other Console Writes until each block finishes?

Yes, this is what [`lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) is for.

```
int currentRequest = 1;
Object lockObject = new Object();
for (int i = 0; i < requests.Count; i++) {
    using (var webclient = new WebClient())
    {
        webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            lock(lockObject) 
            {
               Console.WriteLine();
               ...                
               currentRequest += 1;
            }
        };
        webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("URL HERE"));
    }
}
```

Strictly this does not block other 'console writes', but it does serialize the processing of each response.

> I don't feel like this is how I should be handling requests (asynchronously)

That is true. You should be using [`await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx), [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm not going to write a full example because for handling URLS, there are way way way more complications than just the async. I recommend you also read about [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx) and understand why perhaps your downloads async are perhaps slower than you expect.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for. I knew something seemed odd the way I was handling the urls.

Comment: After swapping the code out using Parallel foreach, it seems to be slower? The lock fixed the issues with the message syncing. Should i expect it to be sower?

Comment: Is hard to say w/o investigating. `Parallel.For` uses a pool of `Task`s and tries to keep the size of pool at a minimum, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/05/26/does-parallel-for-use-one-task-per-iteration/. There is also 'chunking' involved, which means that some iterations starts only after the previous one in the 'chunk' finishes.